# How to add a label to a CopyEvaluate button?

Tags: button

I found a definition of a button

```
Button[Defer[ Information[ \[SelectionPlaceholder], LongForm -> False]], 
  None, BaseStyle -> "CopyEvaluate"]
```

that is doing a good job.

How can I add a label to this button definition similar to `Button[label, action]`? I have trid to change the definition given above, but nothing I've done worked.

Comment: You are using a special pre-defined button style that  gives special treatment to your button's label (`Defer[Information[\[SelectionPlaceholder], LongForm -> False]]`) **is** the label). This means you can't just add a lable to it. What you can do, if anything, to get the effect you want, I haven't figured out.

Comment: @Liam. Button works fine on my system.

Comment: @m_goldberg check edit history it didn't

Comment: I don't get it.. what is this button supposed to do? It looks like all it does is to print `Information[#, LongForm -> False]` when you press it.

Comment: It is an interesting problem if I have got it right. It appears to be able to give information about a selected text when the button is clicked! I agree with @m_goldberg that we are dealing with a button that uses a style and a special kind of label therefore I thought about using `Interpretation` or going to a more low-level function as `ButtonBox`. But, by now, I have nothing. My tests with `Interpretation` change the label but render the button useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `BaseStyle`s like `"CopyEvaluate"` etc I'm afraid you have to stick to that:

> `Button[label,None,BaseStyle->stylename]` inherits `button` functionality from the definition of `stylename` in the`stylesheet`. Such styles typically allow `\[SelectionPlaceholder]` to be **used in label** to represent the currently selected text.

So it is just the matter of the construct. However, you can mimic this behaviour:

```
 Button[
        "the best label",
        Information[Evaluate@CurrentValue["SelectionData"]]
       ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is very slightly better, perhaps?

```
Help[s_] := Information[s, LongForm -> False];
Button[Defer@Help[\[SelectionPlaceholder]], None, 
    BaseStyle -> "CopyEvaluate"]
```

[image: animated gif]